# How to act differently on the first iteration in a Ruby loop?

Tags: ruby

I always use a counter to check for the first item (`i==0`) in a loop:

```
i = 0
my_array.each do |item|
  if i==0
    # do something with the first item
  end
  # common stuff
  i += 1
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this (perhaps a method)?

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this? It is a very real question.

Comment: What prevents you in this case from doing what you need with the first item in the array, then doing a normal `each` loop with just the common stuff?

Comment: @Russell If he does the special thing to the first item (say with `array.first` or `array[0]`) and then runs the `each` loop, he will *still* have to test for the first item if he *doesn't* want to do the regular thing to the first item also.

Comment: Yes but in the example above he *does* want to do the common stuff to the first item. And if he doesn't, couldn't he just do `my_array[1..-1].each`?

Comment: I think Russell means dealing with the first item outside the loop, and then loop from the second item.

Comment: In the example above the common stuff will happen to all items including the first item. If you need to do different things to different elements it doesn't sound like a very good candidate for code in a loop... so I think having it outside the loop makes more sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241684/magic-first-and-last-indicator-in-a-loop-in-ruby-rails is a similar question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do something special first time around in a Ruby loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535293/do-something-special-first-time-around-in-a-ruby-loop)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can do this:

```
my_array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    if index == 0
        # do something with the first item
    end
    # common stuff
end
```

Try it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/JXGph).

Comment: I think this is perhaps not the best answer — it's basically what the OP wrote in his question, but using `.each_with_index` instead of `.each`. The `.drop(1)` suggestion below seems more ruby-like and avoids indexes altogether.

Comment: What if I want to skip the first two iterations? I tried `if index > 1` and got the error 
       `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 47):

Using `each_with_index`, as others have described, would work fine, but for the sake of variety here is another approach.

If you want to do something specific for the first element only and something general for all elements including the first, you could do:

```
# do something with my_array[0] or my_array.first
my_array.each do |e| 
  # do the same general thing to all elements 
end
```

But if you want to not do the general thing with the first element you could do:

```
# do something with my_array[0] or my_array.first
my_array.drop(1).each do |e| 
  # do the same general thing to all elements except the first 
end
```

Comment: +1 I had the same idea. The only difference is when the array is empty.

Comment: I like `my_array.drop(1)` it is more declarative.

Comment: These work, but not in the situation where the special behaviour is in the middle of the loop.  In that case, I expect you need to do each_with_index as the most readable solution..

Comment: If you need to do something special with an element in the middle of a loop, based on its index in the collection, might I be so bold as to say it's likely your code has bigger problems...

Comment: Also, @tokland, I've changed the answer to use `drop`. It is much nicer.

Comment: Should be the best answer, especially with descriptive language like Ruby

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have an "each_with_index" method which is handy for this situation:

```
my_array.each_with_index do |item, i|
  item.do_something if i==0
  #common stuff
end
```

Comment: This is really handy for the classic situation of looping an object in a view when you want to render something different. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

What fits best is depending on the situation.

Another option (if you know your array is not empty):

```
# treat the first element (my_array.first)
my_array.each do | item |
   # do the common_stuff
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`each_with_index` from [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) (Enumerable is already mixed in with Array, so you can call it on an array without any trouble):

```
irb(main):001:0> nums = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
irb(main):003:0> nums.each_with_index do |num, idx|
irb(main):004:1* if idx == 0
irb(main):005:2> puts "At index #{idx}, the number is #{num}."
irb(main):006:2> end
irb(main):007:1> end
At index 0, the number is 1.
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the array afterwards:

```
ar = %w(reversed hello world)

puts ar.shift.upcase
ar.each{|item| puts item.reverse}

#=>REVERSED
#=>olleh
#=>dlrow
```

Comment: Contrary to the code in the question, you are not reversing the first word.

Comment: Yeah, must have imagined an `else` somewhere. But it does do what the title of the question says.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's [`Enumerable#inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) provides an argument that can be used for doing something differently on the first iteration of a loop:

```
> l=[1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> l.inject(0) {|sum, elem| sum+elem}
=> 10
```

The argument is not strictly necessary for common things like sums and products:

```
> l.inject {|sum, elem| sum+elem}
=> 10
```

But when you want to do something *different* on the first iteration, that argument might be useful to you:

```
> puts fruits.inject("I like to eat: ") {|acc, elem| acc << elem << " "}
I like to eat: apples pears peaches plums oranges 
=> nil
```

Comment: Neat and lovely as `inject` is I don't think it answers the OPs question - which was how to do something different for the first iteration of the loop only.

Comment: I don't `inject` fits what he's asking about, but maybe you're seeing something we missed. He wants to do something *different* the first time through an array. His `i += 1` is a manual counter, not a sum.

Comment: @Russel, ha! I got to writing about `inject` and forgot that the whole point of the argument was doing something differently on the first iteration. Thanks.

Comment: @telemachus, updated :) thanks for the notice that it's bed time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't need to be in an immediately enclosing loop and avoids the redundancy of specifying a status placeholder more than once unless you really need to.

```
do_this if ($first_time_only ||= [true]).shift
```

Its scope matches the holder: `$first_time_only` will be globally once; `@first_time_only` will be once for the instance, and `first_time_only` will be once for the current scope.

If you want the first several times, etc, you can easily put `[1,2,3]` if you need to distinguish which of the first iterations you're in, or even something fancy `[1, false, 3, 4]` if you need something weird.